# Why isn't Quadratic Congruences trivially solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: quadratic-residues, np-complete

The Quadratic Congruences problem asks if for constants $a$, $b$, and $c$, does there exist $x$ such that $x<c$ and $x^2 \equiv a\mod b$?

This problem is known to be NP-complete. However I can't find anywhere which states what is $n$ such that this is verifiable in polynomial time as $n$ varies? I presume it's the value of $b$?

However it seems to me that this is trivially solvable in polynomial time - just check every number between $0$ and $c$. Since each number can be checked in polynomial time, this is doable in polynomial time.

What am I missing here? Is it that $x$ can be negative too? But if so $-x^2=x^2$ so isn't this question identical to whether there exist $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv a\mod b$ irrespective of $c$?

I notice I'm confused here so I'm hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think you are missing the definition of "polynomial time".  To be solvable in polynomial time means a bound polynomial in the *size* of the input data.  So we would not be allowed $c$ steps, but only some polynomial in $\log c$ steps.

Comment: See, e.g., [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108598/why-was-primality-test-thought-to-be-np) for a discussion of a similar point of confusion.

Comment: "Polynomial" here means "polynomial in the number of binary digits of $c$. I wonder why the prime factorization of $b$ does not allow a polynomial solution of the problem. Since in this case, the problem could be in P even in the case $P\ne NP$ since factoring is not known to be hard.

Comment: @Peter [Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000078900442) is a paper which discusses that point...they specifically handle the case when $b$ is presented in factored form.  (N.B. I have not studied the paper).

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the relevant $n$ is the length of the input. So $n$ will scale like the logarithm of the input, so that your solution has actually exponential complexity.

Comment: Thanks - I presume that what matters is that it scales with the logarithm of c, since it seems to me that it would still be solvable in polynomial time if it scaled with the lograithm of a or b.

Comment: Yes sorry, I got confused ^^